# SignalR and Redis: SocketFailure on EVAL

Tags: c#, asp.net, redis, signalr

we are running two servers with signalR 2.2.0 and StackExchange.Redis.StrongName 1.0.394 and from time to time we get some errors, like:

```
StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: SocketFailure on EVAL
```

I had a look to the redis log and see no problems there and the performance is always fine. (We also use Redis for caching).

I have no idea what is going on and I would like to know, if I can ignore this error or not. I also asked the hoster if there are any known network issues and they told me that there are not.

The question is not very specific, but I have no idea at the moment where I can get more information.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problems when running Redis 2.4.6.

Once we switched to Redis 2.4.17 the problem was resolved.

Use `redis-cli` and type `info` to get the version of Redis that is actually running.

Comment: have you ever had that problem again ? I currently have it with 2.8.2400